# How to change value in java class(obfuscated file without source)

Tags: java, compilation, hex, inject

I have a **value** in the class file that I need to change, the class file is **obfuscated**, and i **dont** have **source** class.

In a number of versions I managed to do it by simply changing through hex editor - but in a number of newer versions the value shifted.

Theoretical question: how to actually **find the value** (or expression) in the **obfuscated class file**, if we know the value that needs to be changed (I usually take a look through the JD-GUI) and how to change it, ***recompile?*** (There are a lot of classes and libraries in compiled jar, I did not find the correct way to do this through recompilation, specify the right direction, and possible solution if you know). ***Inject?*** (A very extensive and wide area, please specify the method relating to changing the value in a class file of this kind).

The question itself(need solution):

```
 public static int a ()
  {
    If (!b()) {
      return 0;
    }
    String str;
    If (((str = by.d ()) == null) || (str.length () <= 0)) {
      Return 0;
    }
    Return a (str.substring (0, 1), 0);
  }
```

Instead of "return 0;" must be changed to "return 4;"
Previously, (older versions) it was solved using hex editor(because i knew adress that i need to change) and changing

```
9A 00 05 03
```

to

```
9A 00 05 07
```

So this method (through hex adress change), how we can determine the value location in another class that needs to be changed? The value is the same.
Please, if possible, indicate the **direction** (with examples if its possible) in which I need to dig, so that it was not just a valuable experience, but the information helped me **solve the task above**! Or provide same solution(as you see it).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at JByteEdit, a tool to directly edit java bytecode without the need of decompiling or recompiling. It'll be more confusing, though.
[Github link for JByteEdit](https://github.com/QMatt/JBytedit)

Comment: Not working, i need to edit condition, not the final value in this case, JavaByte dont provide similar option